# Windows 10 Provisioned Apps

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a nice clean bloatware free Windows 10 image.

I have used the following line in PS but it seems to remove a lot more than just rubbish apps, but even after running the command, I still have the Minecraft App, Mirror App and Photoshop App.

I know I can remove them through PS individually, but I am hoping to be able to find a good way to nail them all in one go and not remove things such as .NET Frameworks in the process.  I am also using the PS file to make some regedits.

`Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage`

Comment: Can't imagine why this question got downvotes. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a PS script I created to uninstall all apps matching a set name.
you can get the names of apps from this command `Get-AppxPackage` and add it to the variable `$App_To_Uninstall`.

To run this you will need to set execution policy and run this script with an administrative account or and account with equal privileges.

Setting the execution policy can be done using this command using `Set-executionPolicy bypass` don't forget to re-enable this after by changing bypass to default.

```
$App_To_Uninstall=@("officehub","skypeapp","getstarted","bingfinance","Twitter","bingnews","windowsphone","bingsports","xboxapp","solitairecollection","CandyCrush")
foreach ($app in $App_To_Uninstall){
Write-Host "Uninstalling $($app)..." -NoNewline
Get-AppxPackage *$app* | Remove-AppxPackage
} 
pause
```

Comment: This looks a lot more like what I want.  Unfortunately I need to reinstall Windows 10 but that looks like it will work just fine!  I assume this is only for current user?

Comment: Ahhh yes that was my next addition I believe it's as easy as adding a -allusers to the uninstall. Feel free to point it out if Im not